# Setting the default network interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian, linux-networking

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 10.0.0.99
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 10.0.0.1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

After I reboot the machine, I get

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.99 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
```

How can I modify `/etc/network/interfaces` so that my traffic goes
through 10.0.0.1 instead of 10.0.2.2 by default? I can do it manually
as follows, but I don't want to do this on every reboot:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo ip route del default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
vagrant@precise64:~$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.99 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason was unrelated to `/etc/network/interfaces`. This machine was a [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) VM, which by default has some extra stuff in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Make sure eth0 is working. This works around Vagrant issue #391
dhclient eth0

exit 0
```

Commenting out the `dhclient eth0` line and rebooting yields:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ip r
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1  metric 100 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.99 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
```