# Keepalived loses VIP upon power cycle of master

Tags: linux, high-availability, failover, vagrant, keepalived

I have two servers running Keepalived 1.2.7 with hostnames `left` and `right`. Here are the configs:

```
# keepalived.conf on left
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 160
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.10.10.200
    }
}

# keepalived.conf on right
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.10.10.200
    }
}
```

Now I power cycle `left`. Here are what the syslogs look like, interleaved and annotated:

```
>> started servers <<
Aug 15 19:07:32 left Keepalived[4041]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=4043
Aug 15 19:07:32 right Keepalived[4041]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=4043
Aug 15 19:07:33 left Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Aug 15 19:07:33 right Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Aug 15 19:07:33 right Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received higher prio advert
Aug 15 19:07:33 right Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Aug 15 19:07:34 left Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
>> left has 10.10.10.200 <<

>> powered off left <<
Aug 15 19:08:25 right Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Aug 15 19:08:26 right Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
>> right has 10.10.10.200 <<

>> powered on left <<
Aug 15 19:08:58 left Keepalived[1027]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=1029
Aug 15 19:08:59 left Keepalived_vrrp[1029]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Aug 15 19:09:00 left Keepalived_vrrp[1029]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Aug 15 19:09:00 right Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received higher prio advert
Aug 15 19:09:00 right Keepalived_vrrp[4043]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
>> neither has 10.10.10.200 <<
```

I was expecting `left` to take back 10.10.10.200 when it came back up. Why doesn't it? How can I modify my `keepalived.conf`s so that it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the configuration on "right" to look like this:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
state BACKUP
interface eth1
virtual_router_id 51
priority 100
advert_int 1
virtual_ipaddress {
    10.10.10.200
}
```

The **BACKUP** keyword tells keepalived to fail back to the **MASTER** when available.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick. The first section of the logs is a little different (there's no `right ... Received higher prio advert` or `right ... Entering BACKUP STATE`), but the 2nd and 3rd sections are exactly the same, and I still end up with neither server having 10.10.10.200.

Comment: It runs out the issue wasn't Keepalived. I was running this in Vagrant, which does some network configuration on startup. [I should have learned by now](http://serverfault.com/a/538851/133389) :)

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works<del>, though I'm still curious as to why the one in my question doesn't</del>.

```
# keepalived.conf on left
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 160
    advert_int 1
    preempt_delay 15
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.10.10.200
    }
}

# keepalived.conf on right
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    preempt_delay 15
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.10.10.200
    }
}
```

This configuration says to reelect a new master 15 seconds after a higher priority machine comes online.
There's an explanation of the `preempt_delay` option [on the mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.keepalived.devel/1537).

<del>One issue with this configuration: if both machines go down, neither will claim 10.10.10.200 when they come back up.</del> (This was due to the network autoconfiguration that Vagrant does.)

Comment: One server needs to be MASTER, the other needs to be BACKUP.

Comment: I have the same issue with vagrant. Setting states of both machines to BACKUP doesn't help. But adding preempt_delay can solve that.